# Can I avoid creating and deploying projects and just create the business network through API calls?

Tags: hyperledger-composer

(Question is being recorded for future use)

Is there a way to create a business network through the `composer-client` or `composer-admin` API, rather than creating it as its own project?

Answer (score 1):

No, to create a business network definition you must create the folder structure and files yourself as described [here](https://fabric-composer.github.io/tasks/bnd-define.html)